# Getting the Day's high single value instead of series[float] on 5 min time frame using pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

on a 5 min time frame, the total number of bars in a session is 75. For each session I would like to get the highest high (day's high) single value.
But, dayhigh = highest(high, 75) gives a series of float instead of one single high value.
Could anyone help me with pine script to meet above requirement?

Comment: Can you provide the Ticker Symbol so I can have a look.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It should work for any ticker symbol of Indian market. May be we can try for NSE:BANKNIFTY.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this script.

Could you not change the time capture parameters to cover the 75 periods.

Use the settings and turn off the lows, if it works and you don't know how to change code, I can assist.

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/30iJncRa-Initial-Balance-Markets-Time-Zones/

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I will try and incase of any doubt will get back to you.

Comment: I simplified the code shared in the above comment to as shown below
//@version=4
strategy("Day high", overlay=true)
t = time(timeframe.period, "0915-1530")    
var highe_01 = 0.0
if t
    if not t[1]
        highe_01 := high
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
plot(highe_01)
The above logic also provides series of float.
Observation for 1 session of BANKNIFTY on 30th April 2021 5 min time frame:
{33214.95, 33302.60, 33343.80, 33398.85, 33398.85, 33398.85, 33398.85, 33455.25, 33455.25 } Expectation is to get one single value like 33455.25 (day's high)

Comment: The way I coded it I chose not to plot anything until the time session had finished using - plot(not in_time_int_01 ? highe_01 : na, title="Asia High", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr) - not in_time_in_01. How are you using the data? As in are you using the day befores data for the current day?

Comment: I need to use the day's high (highest high value of a particular session) within my trading session for everyday. Lets say my trading session is between 9:30 to 15:30, then within this session, I would require the highest high value. But with above comment's solution, the highest value of current session is available outside the current session bar. Is it possible to get the value within the trading session? But still thank you, I learnt a new technique.

Comment: One request, if in_time_int_01 (only if this is true it will check the below if condition, but the below if condition says, previous bar should not be in session)
    if not in_time_int_01[1]. I am bit confused here. Could you please explain these 2 line of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care at what point the maximum is reached, then you can use the `security()` function. To determine the maximum of the last day

```
dayhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
```

or for the penultimate day

```
dayhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1])
```

Comment: dayhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
The dayhigh mentioned in above code gives the previous day high value. I would like to get the current session (0915: 1530) highest price value in 5 min time frame.